# global variable shows in console as undefined - didn't used to

Tags: javascript, global-variables

This comes as the first javascript declaration in my module:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var json_meets;
var teams;
var my_meet;

window.onload = function() {
    AJAX( '/ajax/getFacilities.html','','populate_datalist_from_array','facilities' );
    AJAX( '/ajax/getAssociations.html','','process_associations','datalist_for_new_team_Association' );
$( "#add_team_dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    window.json_meets = { "meets" : [] };
    window.teams = [];
    window.my_meet = {
        "meet_name" : "",
        "meet_date" : "",
        "meet_id"   : "",
        "meet_location" : "",
        "teams"     : []
    };
}
```

later on I include a file or two that declares this function:

```
function submitTeamToAdd( obj ) {
var doit = 0;

// get Display name of team in input box
var team = document.getElementById( 'add_team_input' ).value;

for ( var i = 0 ; i < window.my_meet.teams.length ; i++ ) {
    if ( getTeamDisplayName( window.my_meet.teams[i] ) == team ) {
        alert( team + ' is already participating.' );
        document.getElementById( 'add_team_input' ).value = '';
        return;
    } 
}   

for ( var i = 0 ; i < window.teams.length ; i++ ) {
    if ( getTeamDisplayName( window.teams[i] ) == team ) {
        doit = 1;
        break;
    }   
}
if ( doit == 1 ) {
    putTeamOnList( team , obj );
} else {
    // open the dialog to add a new team to the database
    openDialog( 'add_team_dialog' );

    // pass thru the name of the team that was entered clear out legacies.
    document.getElementById( 'add_new_team_Name' ).value = team;
    document.getElementById( 'add_new_team_Nickname' ).value = '';
    document.getElementById( 'add_new_team_Association' ).value = '';
    document.getElementById( 'add_new_team_Mascot' ).value = '';
    document.getElementById( 'add_new_team_Classification' ).value = '';
}
}
```

When that function fires, the console throws:

```
TypeError: window.my_meet is undefined
```

How is it undefined?  The variables are declares and initialized inside the window.onload function.  I can understand that they're essentially empty, but that doesn't make them undefined, right?  It should just be an array of length 0.

Comment: "but that doesn't make them undefined, right?" -- where do you assign any value to them? Initialized value has initial value as `undefined` unless you reassign it explicitly.

Comment: The function submitTeamToAdd is called by user action, so it's not being called before onload is complete.

Comment: The weird part is that was alluded to in the title, but not described previously (oops) is that before, I had just ordinary declarations like:

    <script>
    var json_meets = { "meets" : [] };

etc. and I had just the first three lines in the window.onload function.  All of my other function declarations were inline.  I moved most of them into an external file included via a `src` attribute to a `<script>` tag and that's when I started getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined because you didn't define it. You declared it, but it still has a value of `undefined` at the time your function attempts to access it.

`window.onload` fires after all of your resources (including images) have loaded, but you seem to call your function before that happens. You need to wait for the AJAX calls to finish before calling your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **window['my_meet']** everywhere rather than **window.my_meet**

Comment: This is useful when a property contains weird characters. It won't be helpful in this case.